# Title: Leaflet Map Zooming Beyond World Map Boundaries When Zoomed Out

Tags: angular, leaflet

Actual Behavior : Getting gray color when zoom-out map, its going beyond the world map.
Used Below Config Set-Up:

const tileLayer = new TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { noWrap: true });

```
tileLayer.on('load', () => this.layerLoadCompleted());
const centerCoordinates = this.getCenterCoordinates();
this.options = {
  center: latLng(centerCoordinates.lat, centerCoordinates.lng),
  renderer: new SVG({ padding: 100 }),
  zoomSnap: 0.25,
  zoomDelta: this.getZoomStep(), // Default lets set it to 0.25. Values of 0.50 or 0.25 look good
  attributionControl: false,
  layers: [tileLayer]
};
```

}

I tried couple of ways like setting minZoom and maxZoomBounds at that time world map not getting Properly, meaning some portion  of world map only displaying.

## Expected Behavior: When user trying to zoom-out, map should zoom-out till world map not beyond that.